# Angular 2 i18n-internationalisation : message.xlf is empty

Tags: angular, internationalization

I 've been following the angular cookbook for internationalization : https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/i18n.html#!#angular-i18n

after a long dependency debugging time, i manage to generate a message.xlf file, without any error but,
nothing has been extracted, the xlf is empty.

it seems to not see the i18n in my tags...

is there anyone who managed to solve this?

message.xlf

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <xliff version="1.2" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
      <file source-language="en" datatype="plaintext" original="ng2.template">
        <body>
        </body>
      </file>
    </xliff>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I face the same problem, in my case was the angular compiler + typescript 2.1.4, rollback to version 2.0.10 solves the problem.

Comment: Thanks ! it was indeed a typescript's version problem, i uninstalled it and installed the 2.0.8 version and it works

Answer (score 1):

In my case thing was in that I have to start ng-xi18n with parametr '-p path/to/tsconfig.json', because my ts-source files are not in the root, they are in separate directory (src/client/, I've used angular-seed@mgechev to start project from scratch).
I mean my i18n task in package.json looks like:

```
"i18n": "ng-xi18n -p src/client/tsconfig.json"
```

then

```
$ npm run i18n
```

will generate messages.xlf in src/client directory.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue and resolved it by setting the configuration in angular.json as follows:

```
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "<projectName>:build:<configuration>"
          }
         },
```

where:

- projectName: name of your project
- configuration: name of the configuration as provided in 'configurations' section