# angular i18n messages.xlf file is empty

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

I'm using the quickstart template https://github.com/angular/quickstart to build my application. now I'm trying to get the i18n generated messages.xlf file using the command "npm run i18n" as noted in https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/i18n.html but the generated file is empty!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xliff version="1.2" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
  <file source-language="en" datatype="plaintext" original="ng2.template">
    <body>
    </body>
  </file>
</xliff>
```

I'm using the latest @angular/compiler@~2.3.0 along with rxjs@5.0.0-rc.4 and typescript@~2.0.10
Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't have any help unfortunately, but I am running into the exact same problem right now. I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41143020/angular-2-i18n-internationalisation-message-xlf-is-empty) but it looks like you're already on the version of typescript that worked for them.

Comment: Thank you anyway. you may report your issue [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13519) to reopen the existing one.